# What's the Recommended Way to Run CREATE EXTENSION With Salt Stack?

Tags: python, postgresql, deployment, salt-stack

I'm using Salt Stack to manage my Linux servers. I have a command that creates my PostgreSQL database, but I need to run "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;" on my database.

I know I can do this with a shell script that calls psql from the command line, but is there a more sensible way to do this with Salt?

Here's my current DB config script:

```
pg-deps:
    pkg:
        - installed
        - names:
            - postgresql-9.3
            - postgis

dbuser:
    postgres_user:
        - present
        - name: foo
        - password: bar
        - runas: postgres

dbname:
    postgres_database:
        - present
        - encoding: UTF-8
        - runas: postgres
        - owner: foo
        - require:
            - postgres_user: dbuser
```

Comment: Most auto config tools have plugin mechanisms. This might be a good opportunity to write a simple plugin that queries `pg_extension` for a database, and if the ext isn't present or its extversion isn't the current one from `pg_available_extensions`, installs it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a function in the postgres state to execute "CREATE EXTENSION". That would be a very useful addition.

In the meantime, using a 'cmd.run' that runs after the rest of the install should work.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up using.

Comment: Great! Glad that worked for you. 

I'm not sure why this was closed for being "primarily opinion-based". This was a great question.

Comment: Because StackOverflow moderators are zealots